# Another Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Tags: node.js, heroku, restify

I'm trying to build a basic Restify app to Heroku and get the following well known error:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

My port is assigned dynamically:

```
const API_PORT = process.env.PORT || config.get('api.host.port');
```

As I can see in my logs as well:

[image]

I didn't assign this port number and it changes on every restart.

I also removed the 'engines' property from package.json.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using IP `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`.